# ConEmu Layout with multiple columns and rows as startup task

Tags: conemu

We have a rather complex gulp build process that involves several modules where each has one or two watches. I would like to monitor this in one dashboard like this:

[image: ConEmu Layout with several columns and rows]
Each Column is one module, each row inside a column a subsequent build step.
Once the gulp script in column 1 is done, the watch in module 2a (top) will trigger, then 2b (bottom), 3a, 3b, 4a, 4b... you get the idea.

So far I have figured out how to create the columns

```
* -cur_console:t:'1' cmd.exe 
* -new_console:s75H -cur_console:t:"2a" cmd.exe 
* -new_console:s66H -cur_console:t:"3a" cmd.exe 
* -new_console:s50H -cur_console:t:"4a" cmd.exe
```

But cmdemu always takes the previously created console as "parent" to create the new one, so this will obviously fail...

```
* -cur_console:t:'1' cmd.exe 
* -new_console:s75H -cur_console:t:"2a" cmd.exe 
* -new_console:s50V -cur_console:t:"2b" cmd.exe 
* -new_console:s66H -cur_console:t:"3a" cmd.exe 
* -new_console:s50V -cur_console:t:"3b" cmd.exe 
* -new_console:s50H -cur_console:t:"4a" cmd.exe 
* -new_console:s50V -cur_console:t:"4b" cmd.exe
```

Giving me something like this...

[image: wrong layout. it looks cool, though]

How can I create this sort of layout?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, [docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/SplitScreen.html#Working-with-splits) describes how you may split specific pane: just use `T` subswitch to define splitting pane.

```
-cur_console:t:'1' cmd.exe 
-new_console:s75H -cur_console:t:"2a" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s66H -cur_console:t:"3a" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s50H -cur_console:t:"4a" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s2T50V -cur_console:t:"2b" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s3T50V -cur_console:t:"3b" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s4T50V -cur_console:t:"4b" cmd.exe
```

Or, if you want to have sorted tabs

```
-cur_console:t:'1' cmd.exe 
-new_console:s75H -cur_console:t:"2a" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s2T50V -cur_console:t:"2b" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s2T66H -cur_console:t:"3a" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s3T66H -cur_console:t:"3b" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s4T50H -cur_console:t:"4a" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s5T50H -cur_console:t:"4b" cmd.exe
```

Comment: It works perfectly!This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't see that option when I searched the docs mainly because I was looking for `tabs` instead of `splits`. Thanks @maximus for your quick response!

Comment: Hello Maximus
I have a follow-up question. Is there a way to change the console background color of splits? So that 2a and 2b have a color, 3a and 3b another one...

I found the Palettes switch, but nothing on setting just the background: http://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html

(btw, this `-new_console:P:"Tomorrow Night Blue"` doesn't work)

Comment: Thanks, color 1f / 0f did the trick. Sorry for asking you simple questions. I found four pages in your documentation on color and none of them had anything that helped me. Sure, I don't have any knowledge about scripting consoles or anything related to it but then again I'm looking for a tool to speed up my workflow and make my life simpler, not learn another toolset.

Comment: Okay, that's why there was nothing on this topic in the documentation. Maybe you could add this for further reference in case someone else wan'ts to add colors to splits. Thanks for your help Maximus

Comment: @Maximus this is one of the WORST documented things about conemu so I'm shocked your answer was to link to the simple one-page of docs there even is on it that actually if you look, does NOT detail anything about "ADD A LETTER T".  I would gladly offer to re-write the doc for you.....but unfortunately even after using it for many years, you'd also first have to fully explain the magic syntax to me, too. :)  I have yet to meet a single person IRL that can write from scratch any involved tab layout without having to paste together from other people's layouts using pure trial-and-error.

Comment: Splitting syntax was implemented (invented) from scratch and I tried to make it logically understandable. You tell ConEmu what pane to split and in what direction. Simple :) Definitely, as I'm a developer, documentation written by me may be not so clear as it may be. But I appreciate PR with improvements. (In fact, when I need some split configuration, I use the button in Tasks or do some experiments)

Comment: And the `t` switch doesn't belong explicitly to splitting. It has general purpose: https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html#syntax

Comment: The "document" page as you call it does NOT go into ANY detail about this "T" param (I'm a DEV too so please quote these supposed "examples" you keep referring to as they are simply NOT there. Yes, the SYNTAX page which is no more than typing without params (NOT proper documentation nor examples) mentions "T" but here is how clugy this is - create a complex split layout. Go into STARTUP and tell it to use current & restart. 100% of the time it will NOT restore properly at start. It's broken. How about a simple video showing how "easy" this is that we are all missing as it would help very much.

Comment: Examples for using `T` for splitting at the bottom of the page. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/MIZxWHd.png The separate `t` switch is intended for tab names. I don't know how to rephrase "split tab T" which is already in docs.